# React did not mount option tag using setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem were the react `state` did not extract the data in the react-bootstrap `select` form-control tag.  Below are what I did so far:

*state structure*

```
this.state = {
    ... more list
    list: [] // in this list, each item contains { id: 1, name: 'some name' }
}
```

**Some class**

```js
componentDidMount() {
    // ...api fetch and here 
    axios.get('https://api-server.com/test/on/something').then(response => {
        this.setState(state => {
            response.data['something'].map(g => {
                return state.list.push(g);
            })
        }, () => {
            console.log(this.state.list) // it did set the state
        })
    });
}
```

*render()*

```js
<Form.Control as="select">
{
    // the problem is here! can't extract the data
    this.state.list.map(g => {
        return <option value={g.id}>{g.name}</option>
    })
}
</Form.Control>
```

I am not sure why it didn't display each data but I am certainly sure that it did set each item in the `state` correctly.

Comment: You're mutating the existing state `state.list.push(g);` which should never be done in React.

Comment: What does this print? `{JSON.stringify(this.state.list, null, 2)}` add it above your select field.

Comment: @vajad57, it produce an empty array  for some reason, but when I do `console.log(this.state.list)` it return like an empty array then when I collapse the empty array the data are there.

Comment: Try updating the state like this when you get the api response. `this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, list: [ ...prevState.list, ...response.data['something'] ] }))`

Comment: @vajad57, you're awesome! can you post your answer so I can rate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mutating the existing state `state.list.push(g);` which should never be done in React. it's not a good way.

Try something like this instead, cloning everything:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, list: [ ...prevState.list, ...response.data['something'] ] }))
```

Answer (score -1):

I just tried your API URL and it didn't return anything.

Can you check your console to see if it returns something?